# External transcoder with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, amazon-elastic-transcoder, pandastream, zencoder

We want to use an external transcoding service like

- [PandaStream](https://www.pandastream.com/) or
- [Zencoder](https://zencoder.com/en/) or
- [Amazon Elastic Transcoder](http://aws.amazon.com/de/elastictranscoder/)

to transcode videos in our rails app. We are currently using paperclip for asset management (and our own, ffmpeg based processors).

Does Paperclip support handing the actual procssing/transcoding to external services? How would such a processor look like?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that Paperclip has integrations with these services, and I don't know about Zencoder/Elastic, but at least Panda has a first-class Ruby gem, which you use similarly to ActiveRecord models (https://github.com/pandastream/panda_gem).